# Add a custom dijit element to Zend Dojo Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, dojo, zend-form-element

I would like to use Dijit elements that are not included into Zend Framework. But I don't know  how I should go around it :

```
$subPrice = new Zend_Dojo_Form_SubForm('priceTab');
$subPrice->setLegend('Tarification :');

$sign = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Decorator_DijitElement('sign');
$sign->setDijitParams(array('dojoType' => 'dijit.form.ToggleButton',
                    'label'     =>  '-',
                    'showLabel' =>  true,
                    'checked'   =>  true,
                    'onChange'  =>  'toggleLabel(val)'
                                ));
$subPrice->addElement($sign);
```

In my view I just added `dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");` in the javascript

However I get this error message from the `addElement`function :

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object in D:\www\tuto\library\Zend\Form.php on line 1055`

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: What about the getOrder() function?

Comment: Jerec: Have you figured out how to make the togglebutton element? I would like the same thing.

Comment: @Fatmuemoo no, I prepended an image (+/-) to the input, and set `onClick=toggleSign()` so that the js function changes the class of the image's container to display a minus instead of a plus and added a boolean hidden input to know which sign is used